# MediaRecorder Audio Recording Issue

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want playing and recording both simultaneous and 
**After several hours of testing in different devices like** 
Redimi MI, MotoX, Asus Zenfone the bellow recording configuration worked like charm.

But in samsungs like J3 Prime with Android 7, few Samsung galaxies

Recording **without** simultaneously playing audio via MediaPlayer(); **gives clear and sharp recording**

but with audio playing and recording  **gives very noisy output in samsung phones like J3 Prime and other galaxies**, but on other phones like Redimi MI, MotoX, Asus Zenfone as i stated before is clear output.

```
localFileName = getFileName()+".wav";
localFile = new File(localdir, localFileName);
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(localFile.getPath());
```

i cannot get my head out of this issue, if anyone has experience in clear recording configurations, suggestions will be appreciated

Tried reducing the bitrate, sampling rate and encoder but not noisy result in samsung phones when recording is done along with Audio playing via MediaPlayer

Comment: Have you tried using AudioRecorder instead of MediaRecorder?

Comment: i came across that too, but most of the comments about AudioRecorder is to have disadvantages over MediaRecorder which includes manually managing the data buffers and writing to file or encoding.

not sure if all that efforts will pay off, still as i am not able to find any other way out will try that definitely 

Thanks anyway !